# Dynamically mapping HTML Page on click of Menu Items sidebar Component in Ant D pro Reactjs using <Link to = " "> Routing Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
{
   privilegeArray.map((menu, i) => (
     <SubMenu  
       key={i} 
       title={<span className="menus" > <Icon type="appstore" />{menu.screenName}</span>}
       children={menu.MenuItem.map((menuItem, j) => (
         <Menu.Item key={j}>  <Link to={}> <span className="menu-item" > {menuItem.screenName} </span> </Link> 
         </Menu.Item>))} 
     />
  ))
}
```

This is my piece of code for dynamically populating menus in sidebar component from an incoming JSONResponse.

I am stuck on a part that how to link menu items to individual HTML pages whose routes and paths are present in Routes.js.

Comment: Don't you know the paths to route to?

Comment: from here we will get that link dynamic menu?

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings : i know the paths they are stored in routes.js as well. But now there would be multiple menu items each one will have different path so how to provide link to multiple paths at same time ? As we are getting menuItems from a JSONArray Response.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.